# Getting error from Android Webview on Download

Tags: javascript, android, webview, download

Hello I have a a web application from which users can generate PDF reports and download it.

I made changes to the download call in Javascript such that when the user calls the download, a modal message is loaded with a progress message. When the report is generated and downloaded, the progress modal is closed. This works fine on a browser (Chrome)

I also have an Android App that uses a webview to load the same app above. However, when clicking on generate pdf, the modal is shown correctly, but I get a java exception error message:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only download HTTP/HTTPS URIs`

Here is my Javascript function that loads the modal and triggers the download of the pdf file:

```
function utils_teacher_progressDownload_get(url, apptype, modal, defaultfilename)
{
    // Make an AJAX request to the excel script with parameters
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.responseType = "blob"; // Set the response type to blob

    if (modal)
    {
        $('#' + modal).modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false},'show');
        
    }


    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {

                // Process the excel blob and trigger the download
                var blob = new Blob([xhr.response], {type: apptype});

                // Extract the file name from the response headers
                var filename = "";
                var disposition = xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Disposition");
                if (disposition && disposition.indexOf("attachment") !== -1) {
                    var filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
                    var matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
                    if (matches != null && matches[1]) {
                        filename = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, "");
                    }
                }

                var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                var a = document.createElement("a");
                a.href = url;
                a.download = filename || defaultfilename;
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.click();
                URL.revokeObjectURL(url);

                if (modal)
                {
                    $('#' + modal).modal('hide');
                }

            } else {
                // Handle any errors during the AJAX request
                toastr.error("Error while generating Report!");
            }
        }
    };

    xhr.send();
}
```

And I call the above function as follows:

```
utils_teacher_progressDownload_get((url + params), "pdf", "application_modal", "Report Sheet.pdf");
```

Could any one give me an idea where I could be wrong? I would be most grateful!